# iopub_data_rate_limit in google colab when use help()

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

i try to run the code below in google colab, then i got an error.

my code:

```py
import sympy as sp
help(sp)
```

get output:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

how can i fix it?